# Wordpress Page Builder Error

Tags: php, wordpress

Was working on a template in the Aqua page builder, hit save, and the screen went white. I cannot access the page builder anymore and noticed the webpage that is using the template is also just a blank page. 
Using the latest wordpress version with bluehost

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you added some php that is invalid and it is now breaking the website.
 
Do you have ftp access? If so:

- Navigate to that file you were editing e.g. /wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/FILENAME.php, where FILENAME.php is the file that you were editing.
- Remove the last piece of code you added to it should fix the website.
- If that doesn't work then keep removing the code you added until it does work.

Comment: I didn't add any php to the actual webpage since the beginning of development. The Aqua Page Builder gives you a bit of code to insert there [template id="1988"] and the page is then developed through the Page Builder feature. So something happened with the actual page builder I suppose, but have NO idea on how to fix. Can't get a hold of the original developers.

Comment: is your snippet correct? Are you missing the quotes, or any typos?

Comment: The plugin actually will not deactivate.

Comment: If you rename it/remove from the plugin folder (where removing it can be downloading to your desktop, moving to another folder or actually deleting the plugin from the plugin folder.